# asp.net Web server control with child controls, event not firing

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I have a simple web control (TaskList) that can have children (Task) which inherit from LinkButton, that can be added declaratively or programatically.  This works ok, but I can't get the onclick event of a Task to be fired in my code behind. The code ..

```
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:TaskList runat=\"server\"> </{0}:TaskList>")]
[ParseChildren(true)]
[PersistChildren(false)]
public class TaskList : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    //[DefaultProperty("Text")]   
    public TaskList()
    {}

    private List<Task> _taskList = new List<Task>();

    private string _taskHeading = "";

    public string Heading
    {
        get
        {
            return this._taskHeading;
        }
        set
        {
            this._taskHeading = value;
        }
    }

    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]      
    public List<Task> Tasks
    {
        get
        {
            return this._taskList;
        }

        set
        {
            this._taskList = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        foreach (Task task in this._taskList)
            this.Controls.Add(task);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }


    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<h2>" + this._taskHeading + "</h2>");
        writer.Write("<div class='tasks_container'>");
        writer.Write("<div class='tasks_list'>");
        writer.Write("<ul>");
        foreach (Task task in this._taskList)
        {
                writer.Write("<li>");
                task.RenderControl(writer);
                writer.Write("</li>");
        }
        writer.Write("</ul>");
        writer.Write("</div>");
        writer.Write("</div>");
    }
}

public class Task : LinkButton
{
    private string _key = "";

    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this._key;
        }
        set
        {
            this._key = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Markup:

```
 <rf:TaskList runat="server" ID="tskList" Heading="Tasks">
    <Tasks>
        <rf:Task Key="ba" ID="L1" Text="Helllo" OnClick="task1_Click" runat="server" />
    </Tasks>
</rf:TaskList>
```

The Onclick event task1_Click never fires when clicked (although a postback occurs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TaskList needed to implement INamingContainer to correctly route the events of each Task.

Comment: I am bit late to post answer. Still up vote for your find out. :)

Comment: Cheers, I'm trying to persist the TaskList across postbacks, do you know how I get the object ands it's children into viewstate?

Answer (score 2):

You could also inherit from CompositeControl, which implements INamingContainer for you, instead of inheriting from Control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about INamingContainer.